# Hudson + Running parallel jobs

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

I would like to configure a project in Hudson as shown below.

[image]

The starting Job is Job-A. When this job is finished it has to trigger three other jobs, B, C and D together. These three jobs may take different times to complete. Once the jobs B, C and D are finished it has to trigger another job E.

I have seen options like, Pipe line plugin, parameterized plugin etc.These are working fine for the first stage. ie, it will trigger build B, C and D together when job A is completed. But I am stuck at configuring the JOB E in such a way that, it has to start only when all the jobs, B, C & D are finished.

Please assist. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [Join Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Join+Plugin), that will allow you to start B, C, and D after A is finished, then trigger E when they are successfully done.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple DSL Scripts

Example:

```
parallel
(
    {build("job1")}
    {build("job2")}
    {build("job3")}
)
build("job4")
```

here 3 jobs running in parallel phase.
4th job get excuted only after the completion of parallel jobs.

Comment: Which plugin supports that DSL? That example won't work with the "build-flow-plugin" --got this error `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: parallel for class`